# How to compare two C strings?

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char username[50];
  char password[50];
  char passConfirm[50];
  
  cout << "Create a username: ";
  cin >> username;

  cout << "Create a password: ";
  cin >> password;
  
  cout << "Confirm your password: ";
  cin >> passConfirm;

  if (password == passConfirm) {
    cout << "Password confirmed";  
  } else {
    cout << "Password denied";
  }
}
```

Trying to see if the user's input is the same as the user's other input but I don't know how to do it.

I tried that in order to find out if the `password` is the same as `passConfirm` but it won't work and I don't know what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by it won't work?  Will it not compile?  Not run?  Give always say denied?...

Comment: try std::string instead of char[]

Comment: The problem here is attempting to write C++ code in C. Do you know what `std::string` is, how it works, and how to use it?

Comment: For starters use std::string instead of char username[50]; `password == passConfirm` will compare 2 pointers which will never be the same.

Comment: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-stdstring/

Comment: [Turning on your compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/TE1rqeaoP) would have identified your mistake.  Comparing arrays with `==` doesn't compare their contents.  It compares their locations.  `password` and `passConfirm` do not have the same location, regardless of the values stored in them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string username;
  string password;
  string passConfirm;
  
  cout << "Create a username: ";
  cin >> username;

  cout << "Create a password: ";
  cin >> password;
  
  cout << "Confirm your password: ";
  cin >> passConfirm;

  if (password == passConfirm) {
    cout << "Password confirmed";  
  } else {
    cout << "Password denied";
  }
}
```

string is a vector of chars, therefore it is not necessary to create an array of chars

Comment: `**string**` -- Do not use `*` to highlight lines.  The `*` could be confused for a pointer derefence, multiplication, etc.  In addition, another person may want to copy and paste your answer and test it, but then they have to remove those extraneous `*` characters.

Comment: This should have an include for `<string>`.

Comment: Are you referring that `std::string` is `std::vector<char>`?  There is no requirement in the C++ standard for `std::string` to be `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 3):

`char[]` is the C way to do strings. If you're going that way, you need to [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) to compare them.

```
#include <cstring>

...

if (std::strcmp(password, passConfirm) == 0) { ... }
```

But a much better, more C++-friendly way to do this is to use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

```
#include <string>

...

std::string password;
std::string passConfirm;
```

Then the `==` comparison would work as you expect.